# R data.table::fread corrupt csv cell with strange characters

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I tried to read a csv file using data.table:fread.
It works fine with all of my csv files, except one file.

R returns this error:

```
error in fread("<<filename>>.csv", header = FALSE,  : 
  Expected sep (';') but '
' ends field 17 on line 21390 when reading data: "123";"01";"22";"=,ma`1,ia1dNrkYHX>U\\\\";"abc";"123"
```

The seperator is not the problem (I think).
I think the problem is a 'corrupt cell' with strange content:
=,ma`1,ia1dNrkYHX>U\\

When I look in the CSV file, this is indeed the actual content of that cell.

How can I solve this (except deleting the cell in the csv file)?

How can R handle this?

Comment: What does that file look like exactly in the file? Is R escaping anything in the error message? Can you read with `read.csv` and then convert to a data.frame? `fread` is still an experimental function.

Comment: `read.csv` seems to work fine...
But is a lot slower. Because I have a lot of (huge) CSV files, it would be nice to use `fread`.

Comment: If you want further help, I again suggest you paste some data exactly as it appears in the input file by editing your question. Maybe lines 21389:21391, That will help make the problem reproducible and (hopefully) fixable.

Comment: Peter, thanks. It'd be great if you could file it [here](https://api.github.com/repos/Rdatatable/datatable/issues) with a *reproducible example*. By reproducible, I mean, R-code to create a *minimal* (corrupted) file, and then to read it so that we can get the same error. Or you could link us to the corrupted file itself.